# Calling wxHTTP::GetInputStream() from different thread cause wxPROTO_NETERR

Tags: multithreading, http, inputstream, wxwidgets

Here is a sample code:

```
wxHTTP HTTP;
HTTP.SetHeader(_T("Content-type"), _T("application/octet-stream"));
HTTP.SetTimeout(10);

while (!HTTP.Connect(DownloadServer))
    wxSleep(5);

wxApp::IsMainLoopRunning();

std::vector<wxString> FileRecordsToDownload;

{
    wxInputStream* p_HttpStream = p_HttpStream = HTTP.GetInputStream(DownloadDirectory + "TestFile.txt");
    ...
}
```

this code works fine if I run it on main thread, HttpStream ALWAYS returned valid stream. But when I moved that code to another thread sometimes it works fine(especially during debugging) and sometimes it just returning NULL(p_HttpStream = NULL) and HTTP.GetError() returned wxPROTO_NETERR.

I have added calls of wxSocketBase::Initialize(); and wxSocketBase::Shutdown(); in main thread.

Any ideas why is this happening?

**EDITED: SOME UPDATES WITH WORKAROUND**

I have no answer yet why is this happening, maybe the server not responding fast enough, because I checked with different hosting and seems the other one work just fine. But the question is WHY is this happening only when the code is on secondary thread? I find a workaround for this problem:

```
wxInputStream* p_HttpStream = p_HttpStream = HTTP.GetInputStream(DownloadDirectory + "TestFile.txt");

while (HTTP.GetError() != wxPROTO_NOERR)
{
    wxSleep(1);
    p_HttpStream = HTTP.GetInputStream(DownloadDirectory + "TestFile.txt");
}
```

So the question is not closed, if anyone know the root of the problem please comment.

Comment: what is you platform/compiler and wx version? Did you use any non-default configuration when building wx? I see you are trying to work with "DownloadSewrver" - maybe it will be better to use wxFTP?

Comment: At what point are you calling wxSocketBase::Initialize()? Can you make sure it is called before secondary thread is created.